# Inbound/outbound not supported on linktype 1 when reading savefiles

Tags: c, linux, wireshark, pcap, libpcap

To get incoming packet from a pcap file. I set "inbound" filter in pcap_compile() and here is partial code.

```
  pcap = pcap_open_offline("test.pcap", errbuf);
  if (pcap == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "error reading pcap file: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
  }

  char filter_exp[] = "inbound";
  struct bpf_program pgm;
  if (pcap_compile(pcap, &pgm, filter_exp, 0, PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN) == -1) {
    printf("Bad filter - %s\n", pcap_geterr(pcap));
    return 1;
  }

  if (pcap_setfilter(pcap, &pgm) == -1) {
    printf("Error setting filter - %s\n", pcap_geterr(pcap));
    return 1;
  }
```

But here is error message.

> Bad filter - inbound/outbound not supported on linktype 1 when reading savefiles

I just googled and found the possible solutions.

[How to filter the inbound packet by libpcap in C:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878253/how-to-filter-the-inbound-packet-by-libpcap-in-c)

> The "inbound" filter is not available for the Ethernet link type (a cooked capture would have it eg.). Is it sufficient for your needs to filter on destination MAC or IP address ?

[How to determine packet direction using libpcap:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815485/how-to-determine-packet-direction-using-libpcap)

> The source or target IP address is sufficient. If the source is local, it's outbound. If the target is local, it's inbound. If neither, it's a promiscuous sniff.

Looks like the only way is to determine if the packet's target IP address is local or not. But how to know the local IP address from a pcap file?

Comment: You can't tell unless one of the devices is the machine you're running the program on, then you can get the MAC addresses of all your interfaces.

Comment: So there is no way to determine the inbound packets for Ethernet link tye from pcap file ?

Comment: That's what the documentation you quoted says.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if there is any other information from a packet to know its direction?

Comment: If your pcap file contains Wireless packets, you may be able to use [the DS flag](https://dalewifisec.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/the-to-ds-and-from-ds-fields/).

Comment: @pchaigno I think that's only for packets between APs in a Wireless Distribution System, not packets to/from PCs. But I could be misunderstanding.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think it's only for Wireless Distribution Systems. I tried it on my own wireless network by sniffing traffic from a phone. `DS=0x1` when a packet exits the phone via the AP and `DS=0x2` when it enters the phone (via the AP). See https://superuser.com/a/1038580/775055 for more information, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50454901/6884590 for a capture/BPF filter that matches the DS flag.

Comment: @pchaigno Thanks for the clarification. It seems like that SO question would make a good duplicate of this, do you agree?

Comment: That SO question is specific to IEEE802.11 and not really asking the same question (even if the answer applies to both). The present question is not specific to IEEE802.11 as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barmar is right in that you can't know for sure if an IP address is local from your pcap file only. However, if you know the pcap **wasn't captured on a promiscuous interface**, you may **try to guess the address of the interface**.

You can either guess the IP or the Ethernet address. The Ethernet address is probably best since you may not have only IP packets in your pcap file. It may however be less clear which Ethernet address is your interface's because the gateway's address will also be in a large number of packets.

---

**Guessing the interface's Ethernet address**

```
$ tshark -r tmp.pcap -T fields -e eth.src -e eth.dst | grep -Po "(\w{2}:){5}\w{2}" | sort | uniq -c
     11 01:00:5e:00:00:01
     41 01:00:5e:00:00:fb
     11 01:00:5e:00:00:fc
     27 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa
     34 00:00:00:00:00:01
     31 00:00:00:00:00:fb
  11815 00:00:d9:97:5b:37
    905 00:00:eb:12:48:d6
  11115 00:00:b0:7b:ce:08
     80 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Each Ethernet address is displayed with the number of packets it's contained in (as source or destination). The Ethernet address with the largest number of packets is *likely* your interface's. The second largest one is *likely* the gateway's.

Packets with the interface's address as destination are inbound packets, and vice versa.

---

**Guessing the interface's IP address**

```
tshark -r tmp.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst ip | grep -Po "(\d+.){3}\d+" | sort | uniq -c
```

Same principle here, you should see one IP address with a large number of packets. That's *likely* your interface's.